# Make input fill the entire free space in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Here is how my navbar should look:

[image]

As you can see there is a `logo`, `loop icon`, `clear icon` and `input field` that takes all the space between those two icons (no matter what resolution).

Here is how my navbar looks now:

[image]

I have tried several different aproches to fill the empty space with `input` without breaking responsive features, but I have failed.

**How can I make `input field` fill the entire space between these two icons on every screen?**

**[Here is plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y1ViBy1us2Ap7mnhSeSZ?p=preview)**

Comment: you have to use flexbox... i will try to edit your plunker

Comment: Example: http://www.bootply.com/FUOWTa37gL

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace your form with

```
 <form class="navbar-form">
        <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
          <div class="input-group" style="display:table;">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:1%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
            <input class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search Here" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" type="text">
             <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:1%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </form>
```

I hope it helps.